# Find an approximation of the unique real root of $6x^3+2x^2-x-1$

Tags: inequality, numerical-methods, roots, approximation, newton-raphson

I'm searching a way to find an approximation of the (unique) real root of $6x^3+2x^2-x-1$ . I can use the Newton Method, but I don't know how to find a number that can allow me to start the recursive process. Is there another simpler solution?

Basically, I want to prove that the equation has only one real root, so I can solve the inequality.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by approximation of $6x^3+2x^2-x-1>0$?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to approximate? Do you wish to find the roots of the polynomial on the LHS?

Comment: Try ${1 \over 2}$.

Comment: Yeah, and finding the root could allow me to solve the inequality I think; @copper.hat how you find it?

Comment: The root is simple and there is exactly one, so you could use bisection to find it.

Comment: By the rational root theorem, if there is a rational root, it's one of $\pm 1, \pm\frac12,\pm\frac13$ or $\pm \frac16$. It's not too hard to check those.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't a rational root!

Comment: Seriously?   6(1/2)^3+ 2(1/2)^2- (1/2)- 1= 6/8+ 2/4- 1/2- 1= 3/2- 3/2= 0.  copper hat had already said that!

Comment: @user247327, um, 6/8=3/4, not 1....

Comment: @user247327 Check your additions skill, no hate but I'm not so stupid, your equation does -1/2 lol

Comment: By simple I meant not repeated. My suggestion above was for a starting point for Newton's iteration.

Comment: But I don't understand how I can prove that the solution is only one!

Comment: Are you asking how to prove the cubic has just one root?

Comment: Yes; I know that cubic can have 1 or 3 (real) solutions; how can I prove that there is only one?

Comment: @L.Repetti: See my comment to the answer below.

Comment: You can show that $f$ has a local $\min$ at $x_1 = - ({2+ \sqrt{22} \over 18} )
> -{1 \over 2}$. Note that for $x \le 0$ we have $f(x) \le 2x^3+2x^2-x-1 = (x+1)(2x^2-1)$ from which it follows that $f(x) < 0$ for $x \in [-{1 \over 2}, 0]$ and hence $f$ is strictly decreasing until it hits a local $\min$ after which it is strictly increasing. Combining these facts, along with the fact that $f$ is a cubic shows that $f$ has a unique real root (which is positive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Noticing that $f(0)=-1, f(1)=6$ allows us to conclude that there is a root in [0,1] by the IVT. So we can simply do Newton's with starting value $1/2$ to find the root, and thus solve the inequality

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but how can i have the proof that it is the only solution?

Comment: $f$ has a local $\min$ and $\max$. Show that the local $\max$ is negative, and use this to reason that $f$ has exactly one real root.

Comment: But how are you sure there is one and only one root?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla: I added a comment above outlining how you could prove that $f$ has exactly one real root. Basically the idea is that since $f$ is a cubic and it has a local $\max$ somewhere. If the value at the local $\max$ is negative, then $f$ can only cross the real axis at one point (otherwise the local $\max$ would occur between the zeros and be non negative).